Explain how π – 1 + 50 + ⅔ × 1000 is PLONK
The clue comes from a Guardian Newspaper cluing competition from 2020.

It’s carelessly set down: π – 1 + 50 + ⅔ × 1000 (5)

The answer is PLONK.

It’s carelessly set down = PLONK
π – 1 = P [Pi - i = P]
+ 50 = L [L is Roman numeral for 50]

That leaves: "+ ⅔ × 1000".
Is the K derived from 1000? If so ⅔ must be ON which I don't get.
Also it's "+ ⅔ × 1000" and not "+ ⅔ + 1000". Can "⅔ × 1000 = 666.666…" mean ONK somehow?

I would think that it is:
Pi - 1 (I) = P
50 = L
2/3 × 1000 = 2/3 x (ONE thousand) = (two-thirds of ONE) K = ONK

I don't have the rep to add a comment, but kagami's explanation is correct.
The clue setter's own explanation was presented in this comment:
https://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/crossword-blog/2020/mar/30/crossword-roundup-fancy-learning-cryptic-crosswords-during-coronavirus-lockdown#comment-139571305
as "Pi + L + ONe K"

Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This could make a good answer in its own right if you were to [edit] it to quote the author's reasoning directly instead of just linking to it, as links tend to die out over time.

Thanks for the comments - edited to do this.
